# BigQuery calculation to count how many unique combinations of 4 items there are across 6 columns

Tags: google-bigquery, sliding-tile-puzzle, zebra-puzzle

I have the following table (I have covered up the current_holder column for privacy reasons):

[image]

For each row, I want to find the number of times we could pull 4 unique objects out of a bag (the objects being keys, skulls, gems, coins, daggers and crowns) without return. For example, in row 1 I could do this 6 times since once all of the skulls are taken out there are now only 3 unique objects left in the bag. For row 2 there is no way of pulling out 4 unique objects. For row 3 I could do this 5 times since after all the skulls are taken out there would still be one more combination of 4 unique objects left.

Does anyone know how I could calculate this number in BigQuery?

Comment: I don't understand what is the expected output of your table, is the output only the column names that remain or the amount of movements that you did to retain your 4 unique objects? From what I understand the answer posted is good.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the sum of the 3 lowest values.

- row 1: the lowest 3 are `[0, 0, 6]` so the sum is 6.
- row 2: `[0, 0, 0]` -> 0
- row 3: `[0, 4, 5]` -> 9

This query calculates that:

```sql
WITH
  table_1 AS (
  SELECT
    15 AS key,
    6 AS skull,
    34 AS gem,
    0 AS coin,
    0 AS dagger,
    12 AS crown,
    1 AS row_num
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    5 AS key,
    0 AS skull,
    0 AS gem,
    0 AS coin,
    0 AS dagger,
    0 AS crown,
    2 AS row_num
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    9 AS key,
    4 AS skull,
    12 AS gem,
    0 AS coin,
    5 AS dagger,
    5 AS crown,
    3 AS row_num),
  arrays AS (
  SELECT
    ARRAY(
    SELECT
      x
    FROM
      UNNEST([key, skull, gem, coin, dagger, crown]) AS x
    ORDER BY
      x
    LIMIT
      3) AS arr,
    row_num
  FROM
    table_1 )
SELECT
  SUM(x) AS num_unique,
  row_num
FROM
  arrays,
  UNNEST(arr) x
GROUP BY
  row_num;
```

(It is a little verbose...you could probably do this simpler but it works to calculate the number you are looking for.)